# Generating random poisson numbers

Tags: python, random, poisson

I was writing a function (without using the random.poisson function)that generates a random number from a poisson distribution with lambda a.

When running the function with different parameters, I always get 0. I guess it is the algorithm problem but don't know where is wrong.

Here is my code.

```
#takes a as lambda (mean)
def random_poisson(a):
    x = 0
    p = 1
    while p >= math.exp(a):
        i = random.random()
        p = p * i
        x += 1

    return x
```

Trying out different lambda values:

```
print(random_poisson(3))
print(random_poisson(5))
print(random_poisson(math.log(5)))
```

The output:

```
0
0
0
```

Thanks so much!

Comment: Please give an example of the parameters that you used.

Comment: @DYZ I added the examples :)

Comment: You should pre-calculate `math.exp(-a)` and use the stored result in your `while`'s comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any positive `a`, `math.exp(a)` is greater than 1, but `p` is 1. The loop condition is never true, the loop is never executed, and your function returns the initial value of `x`.

Comment: Oh I got you! It should be -a, instead of a. Thanks so much!